# How to get Device supported Locales?

Tags: java, android, locale

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales()) `getAvailableLocales()` should return the list of all installed Locales yet the OS is not able to identify some of the Locales in the list.

Is there any way to get the List of Locales which is displayed under Settings?

Comment: Have you tried it in diff handsets and APIs?

Comment: I have tried in 2 devices. One device lists the Language i am aiming in Settings + `getAvailableLocales()` also returns the Locale. Hence all works well.

The other one does not list it in settings but `getAvailableLocales()` returns the Locale. Encoding error on that device. Looking for a reliable API.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like some device specific issue then.. try it on lollipop and below and marshmallow and above.

Comment: Well looks to me like even though the Locale is supported it is not enabled/installed by the OEM.